# How to fill area under line plot in seaborn

Tags: python, visualization, seaborn, line-plot

I want to fill the area under a line plot so it looks as the picture below:
[image: it should look like it]

instead of

[image]

built on the following .csv file:

```
01-01-97    1
01-02-97    2
01-03-97    3
     ...
01-11-17    251
01-12-17    252
01-01-18    253
```

what should I change in this code to generate the desired graph?

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# load csv
df=pd.read_csv("test.csv")
# generate graph
g = sns.lineplot(x="Date", y="Data", data=df)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
plt.fill_between(df.Date.values, df.Data.values)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternative, using a *stacked* line chart:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# load csv
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")

# generate graph
plt.stackplot(df["Date"], df["Data"], alpha=0.5) 

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

To fill area under the curve of faceted plots, you can also use `Axes.fill_between()`, like in the very convenient function posted in [this GitHub ticket](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/2410#issuecomment-753474050). Full credit goes to Michael Waskom, I am just copying his work below for convenience.

```py
def fill_under_lines(ax=None, alpha=.2, **kwargs):
    if ax is None:
        ax = plt.gca()
    for line in ax.lines:
        x, y = line.get_xydata().T
        ax.fill_between(x, 0, y, color=line.get_color(), alpha=alpha, **kwargs)
```

He also gave an alternative solution leveraging Seaborn's object interface in [a later answer to the same ticket](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/2410#issuecomment-1246054261).

```py
import seaborn.objects as so
so.Plot(data, "xname", "yname").add(so.Line()).add(so.Area(edgewidth=0))
```